# React Redux clean way to update nested objects?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a reducer with an initial state that looks something like this:

```
const initialState = {
  person: {
    details: {
      addresses: {...},
      invoices: {...},
    },
    tasks: {
      option1: [...],
      option2: [...],
      option3: [...]
    }
  }
}
```

I **WAS** updating the state within the reducer by doing something like this:

```
export const exampleReducer = (state = {...initialState}, action ) => {

  case actions.AN_ACTION:
    state.person.tasks.option1 = [new array]
    state.person.tasks.option2 = [another array]
    return state

  default:
    return state
}
```

But I was brought to attention this link: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/ which recommends doing something like this:

```
function updateVeryNestedField(state, action) {
  return {
    ...state,
    first: {
      ...state.first,
      second: {
        ...state.first.second,
        [action.someId]: {
          ...state.first.second[action.someId],
          fourth: action.someValue
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a neater way to go about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your sample code is mutating the existing state.  As that docs page shows, you need to make a copy of *every* level of nested data in order to create a correct immutable update.

That's one of the reasons why [we strongly recommend using the Immer library for immutable updates](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-immer-for-writing-immutable-updates), preferably as part of [our new official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org).

Comment: Ahh I see. Ill take a look at that now!